# Error 500 MVC with subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a PHP MVC frame work.
I created a subdomain but it gives the error 500.

My root `.htaccess` file is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    all_users/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) all_users/$1    [L]
```

It redirects to the "all_users" folder.

The "all_users" root `.htaccess` is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

The subdomain folder is in root of site.

How should I change the `.htaccess` file(s) for subdomain
redirection. Thanks.

Comment: look at the error logs for details about the 500.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

**This is the .htaccess file in root of site:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /  [L] 

    RewriteRule    ^$  all_users/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) all_users/$1    [L]

 </IfModule>
```